# Service and systemd module asks for sudo password

Tags: ansible

I'm having an issue where the Ansible service module is failing due to a sudo password issue:

```
fatal: [192.168.1.10]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 192.168.1.10 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "sudo: a password is required\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}
to retry, use: --limit @/Volumes/HD/Users/user/Ansible/playbooks/stop-homeassistant.retry
```

My playbook has just one task, to stop the service.  It looks like:

```
---
- hosts: 192.168.1.10
  tasks:
    - name: Stop Homeassistant
      become: true
      service: name=home-assistant@homeassistant state=stopped enabled=yes
```

Or, in the case of systemd:

```
      systemd: state=stopped name=home-assistant@homeassistant enabled=yes
```

I'm running the playbook like so:

```
ansible-playbook -u homeassistant playbooks/stop-homeassistant.yml
```

However, passwordless sudo is setup for that user on that box (in /etc/sudoers.d):

```
homeassistant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/systemctl restart home-assistant@homeassistant
homeassistant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/systemctl stop home-assistant@homeassistant
```

If I ssh into that box as homeassistant, and I run:

```
 sudo systemctl stop home-assistant@homeassistant
```

The home-assistant@homeassistant service will stop cleanly without asking for a sudo password.

Any idea why the systemctl command would run perfectly as the user on the box, but then fail in the service/systemd module?

Comment: Do you obtain the same failure with the service module?

Comment: Try debugging via `-vv` or `-vvv`

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni yes, same failure.

Comment: At this point, it seems like deeper in how Ansible interacts with systemd.

If the service is stopped and I run the playbook that stops the service, it works.  If I run it with the start service, I get the failure, and vice versa...

In other words, if the service is started and I run the playbook that starts th service, it works.  If I run the stop service, I get the failure.  It just seems like Ansible can't actually affect anything.

Comment: @Kyslik See my message above.  In a success scenario, the message Ansible gets back is a good status message.  In a failure, it's a failure message.

`<192.168.1.10> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o 
...ipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\n')
fatal: [192.168.1.10]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "failed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "daemon_reload": false,

Comment: More info:  I see this in /var/log/messages:

`Jun 11 00:15:17 192.168.1.10 ansible-systemd: Invoked with no_block=False name= enabled=True daemon_reload=False state=stopped user=False masked=None`

Does that "user=False" mean anything?  Is the user not getting to the systemd call from Ansible?

Answer (score 2):

Try configuring passwordless sudo on your target machines:

```
homeassistant ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Configuring specific commands with a `NOPASSWD` flag in `/etc/sudoers` does not work with Ansible.

Details here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5712

Comment: Wow, that's great to know.  Unfortunately id din't solve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, please modify your playbook as below:

  `hosts: 192.168.1.10
  remote_user: home-assistant
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root 
  tasks:
    - name: Stop Homeassistant
      become: true
      service: name=home-assistant@homeassistant state=stopped enabled=yes`

Now,

Run as `ansible-playbook <playbook-name>`.

If above command fails due to password, please run as

`ansible-playbook playbook.yml --user=<username> --extra-vars "ansible_sudo_pass=<yourPassword>"`

Comment: Same result, but now I'm required to enter in homeassistant's password.  I also don't understand why I would have to enter in the password when I don't have to when I'm ssh'ed in.  Isn't that what -u is for?

Comment: It's asking password because we explicitly specify it.

Comment: Your modified answered worked!   However, my strategy was to avoid using root if possible, and just give enough permissions to the homeassistant user to do its thing.

I then started to pare back the directives and found the difference to be the become_method.  For some reason, I need that directive to be in the playbook.  Therefore, now my original playbook while running with the -u flag with "become_method: sudo" now works.  

I don't fully understand why because default become_method is already sudo, but I'm just happy that it now works.  

Thank you!